# Build a non minimized project with dart2js

Tags: dart, dart2js, dart-2

Have a project builds and runs with `webdev serve` ok. With `webdev build` it builds and deploy fine, but crashes when loading in the browser. In order to do better debugging I would like a non-minimized build, but got hit by some other error.

Have now backed to a unmodified standard boilerplate project from the dart-sdk and same error, see below.

With dart-sdk 2.1.0-dev.4.0, creating the a project from the template.

"description: An absolute bare-bones web app."

`webdev serve` builds and run fine.
`webdev build` Also builds and run fine.

For 
`webdev build --no-release`
The project builds, but when loaded got

```
main.dart.js:64 GET http://localhost/packages/build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler_stack_trace/stack_trace_mapper.dart.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:64
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:81
main.dart.js:71 GET http://localhost/packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:71
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:81
```

Is the `--no-release` used wrong, should the environment be different, are there other ways to build a non-minimized build?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple temporary workaround, that seems to do the trick.

First deploy with

```
webdev build -o builddir
```

Then overwrite generated `main.dart.js` with

```
dart2js -o builddir/web/main.dart.js web/main.dart
```

Apart from the source mappings aren't setup correct in my environment it seems to work correct.